# Ember -- JSON API Adapter Error Handling

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I want to take a specific action when an API request results in a 404 error.  I've read that the appropriated way to do this would be handling the error in the application adapter like below:

```
  handleResponse: function(status, headers, payload){
    if(status === 404 && payload.errors){
      //handle error
    }
    return this._super(...arguments);
  }
```

The problem is, as soon as I set up the adapter, it won't finish loading the page so I can handle the error on the page itself.  Instead, it automatically takes me to some error route that just says "Adapter error".  How can I stop/override this behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I needed to adjust the handleResponse hook in the application adapter to pass the new requestData parameter to the super method.

```
handleResponse (status, headers, payload, requestData) {
    return this._super(status, headers, payload, requestData);
},
```

Then I just changed the first line of the code in my question from

```
handleResponse: function(status, headers, payload) {
```

to

```
handleResponse: function(status, headers, payload, requestData) {
```

I was then able to catch and handle the error

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could handle it on a request basis like below:

```
return this.get('store').find('user', userId).then((user) => {
    this.set('user', user);
}).catch((reason) => {
    var possible404 = reason.errors.filterBy('status','404');
    if(possible404.length !== 0) {
      // Handle 404 error
    }
});
```

Although this is not the solution that you wanted, this alternative will allow you to customize more. By the way, the automatic behavior seems to be the [application-error substates](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_code-error-code-substates) kicking in on 404, so give it a read if you want to override the behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I came up with another answer awhile ago, but forgot that I had posted this.  I'll post the answer I came up with.